# need to do a cc on this code

Tags: php, html

this is what i have so far, right now the orders are being sent as a confirmation but i a copy sent to me as well what do i need to add?

```
  $EMAIL=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"EMAIL");
    $to = $EMAIL;
    $subject = "Florida Fields To Forks - Order Confirmation";
    $message = "Thank for your order! You can check your order here: http://www.floridafieldstoforks.com/order.php?orderid=$orderid";
    $from = "floridafieldstoforks@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

i added "cc but it didnt work any suggestions would be awesome ty

Answer (score 1):

Just put the cc like you put the from like this:

```
$EMAIL=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"EMAIL");
    $to = $EMAIL;
    $subject = "Florida Fields To Forks - Order Confirmation";
    $message = "Thank for your order! You can check your order here: http://www.floridafieldstoforks.com/order.php?orderid=$orderid";
    $from = "floridafieldstoforks@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers.= "\n"."Cc:" . $cc;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: just putting the cc header won't do

Comment: i tried the code but it wouldnt send a copy of the email to myself

Comment: wouldnt it have to be $cc =""floridafieldstoforks@gmail.com";

Comment: you need to assign an email address for the $cc var.
as Ryan B. says

Answer (score 0):

couple of changes to be done. first create a cc header. And then add the cc address to the `$to` variable.

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Cc: ccaddress@google.com';

$to = $to . ", ccaddress@gmail.com";
```